# Sending Raster File in ArcMap, Attributes Gone

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

On my computer, I opened a .tif file in ArcMap 10.1 and reclassed the values into two categories - this results in a new file. I then send that file to another computer and open it in ArcMap but rather than having two distinct values the raster is displayed as a stretch. When I try to get unique values, nothing happens. Solutions? Thanks.

Comment: save the lyr file with the tif, should with the reclassification - ArcMap does not change the tiff (arcmap interpretation does)